# How to add a new user in my xmpp server using my android app?

Tags: java, android, xmpp, chat, openfire

Hi guys maybe my question is easy but I'm noob in android :C,  I'm building a chat app in android and I need add new users (clients) to my server openfire xmpp, but I need do it automatically so, there is any way to do this? I mean the users will open the app and the first screen will be the sing up screen, my question here is how can I do that?

Comment: There are many many examples on how to do this if you google something like 'android login screen'

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [openfire plugins](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html) concept. The openfire plugins have capabilities to extend the functionality of the openfire server.

Now, create an openfire plugin with a servlet that can take requests from your android application. Basically the servlet has to take the username, password, domain...so forth and talk to openfire.

Upon clicking the signup button, take the information from UI and invoke the  openfire plugin servlet. That servlet can read your information and talk to openfire, create an account and respond back with status.

Use the status information information to present the status on User Interface.